# TypeError: undefined is not an object in React

Tags: reactjs

I am beginner with React, do not know how to fix this, to get my first app up and running:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["PropTypes"].func')
```

Following this tutorial: Lynda - Building and Deploying a Full-Stack React Application. Googled the error message. I tried to add this line: `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` Apparently it did not help.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Along with the answer below: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 3):

`prop-types` is a [`npm package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) and does not come in the default installation using `create-react-app`. It must be install using `npm` or `yarn` and imported like this

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Meantime I installed `prop-types`, but still when I put in `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'` i.e. in the index.js, it did not help but get warning: `'PropTypes' is defined but never used.` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to import where you're using. Inside `InternalPropTypes.js`

Comment: Hi! I am still stuck. Applied your suggestion, but I do not know what else I need to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671024/how-to-fix-proptypes-issue I do not found any `InternalPropTypes.js` file.