# How to fix "PropTypes" issue?

Tags: reactjs

Doing *Lynda - Building and Deploying a Full-Stack React Application* tutorial, and get stuck at a point, get following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["PropTypes"].func')
```

I installed `prop-types` module like this:
`npm install prop-types`

Resolved all vulnerabilities with:
`npm audit fix`

Added some code in the only file where `props` was used based on this page: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

[image]

But I still get the same error. Do you have any idea what to do? I am a newbie with relay.

Comment: The error occurs in `react-router` package. Not in your code. Which react router version do you use? `PropTypes` were moved to a separate from  react package quite some time ago.

Comment: Can you show package.json, especially dependecies. Also try to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.

Comment: Hi @TalgatSaribayev Restart IDE helped and now I get a new error. I removed `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. Attached the dependency lines from `package.json`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671393/babel-5-plugin-is-being-run-with-an-unsupported-babel-version-tried-to-update-b

Answer (score 0):

Please change import from 'react' to 'prop-type'

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Comment: Hi! I have both lines: `import React, {Component} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`

Comment: Try to close and restart the IDE.

Comment: Hi! Restart IDE helped, or at least I got a new error now. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671393/babel-5-plugin-is-being-run-with-an-unsupported-babel-version-tried-to-update-b